# How are high level and creative positions obtained?

Tags: career-development

I tried three approaches so far, all three kind of successfully in they scope but with only as much results as described:

1. If you work to rule, minimum they can force out of you through they processes, trying not to be caught on any management initiatives kind of "here is your chance now, important project, lots of freedom, right for your skills, just take it", you do not interfere anybody but understandably have lots of restrictions what you can do.
2. If you try to work well, use your skills and competence, apply initiative and creativity, the supervisor immediately is seeing the competitor to him, kills your project first and forces you out of the company second regardless of how good your results actually are. Here we talk about projects that have been initially approved for you, not something done without permission.
3. If you concentrate on pleasing your supervisor first, you are ultimately recognized as a perfect low level executioner that lacks any capability to go beyond this. "These are good but we need different people able to take the lead" and the open position is annouced you would not get if applying. For somebody who went through #2 before, simply awesome.

How are actually higher positions ever obtained? People do become something: lead developers, software architects, managers, presidents. By which exactly means? Sorry, just need to understand how does the world work.

Comment: What makes you think #2 is actually happening outside of soap operas und truly horrific shops? Did something like that happen to you? Maybe it would be better to ask about this, specific real scenario instead.

Comment: IMO judging by the companies I have worked at, a lot of the time it is nepotism.

Comment: For what I've seen, you wait for someone with the high level position you like to resign or retire.

Comment: @12345ieee: usually, in those situations, retirement is announced at the same time with the new person filling the position. So, waiting is not really the answer, it is just unavoidable.

Comment: How about 4. Apply for the position? Most of these are filled from outside the company. So, apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend spending less effort on pointless stereo typing and more effort looking at your specific situation. Each situation is different.

Personally I had good luck with a version of number 2: Do good work and have fun doing it. In my experience the reaction of the employer has almost always been delight and encouragement and not what you describe.

When I became a leader myself, developing my people was always one of my highest priority. One job as a leader is to make yourself obsolete: find or grow people to be better than you and that can replace you. If that actually happens (which is IMO a success) a new and better opportunity will present itself for you.

If you indeed have an employer, job or environment that actively hinders your growth: find a new one. There are plenty of good ones out there. You only have one career. Life is too short to waste it on crappy employers, jobs, or projects.

If you find yourself repeatedly in the same bad situation than perhaps the problem lies with you: Take an honest look at your behavior and decisions and look for ways to act differently.